# How do I use Jolt to json array to nested json?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Am new to nifi(1.14) and using JOLTTransform processor to transfer the input json (flatten) to nested json. I could not able to fix with the JOLT Schema. kindly help me on this.

The input JSON is :

```json
[
  {
    "executionTime": "2244",
    "processorId": "3ef03f9c-b42c-4c4e-9d5f-d14878bb2c84",
    "filename": "Trading",
    "processStartTime": "2021-07-26 16:31:19",
    "processSQL": "TradingDetails.sql",
    "executionFetchTime": "2049",
    "sourceCountValue": "5076",
    "startTime": "1627297279651",
    "processGroupName": "Trading"
  },
  {
    "ProcessEndTime": "2021-07-26 16:31:29",
    "completedTime": "1627297289412",
    "processDuration": "0",
    "destCountValue": "5076",
    "tableName": "TRADINGDETAILS"
  },
  {
    "ProcessEndTime": "2021-07-26 16:31:29",
    "completedTime": "1627297289412",
    "processDuration": "0",
    "destCountValue": "5076",
    "tableName": "CUSTTRADINGDETAILS"
  }
]
```

and the expected JSON output is

```json
{
  "Trading": {
    "Source": {
      "executionTime": "2244",
      "processorId": "3ef03f9c-b42c-4c4e-9d5f-d14878bb2c84",
      "filename": "Trading",
      "processStartTime": "2021-07-26 16:31:19",
      "processSQL": "TradingDetails.sql",
      "executionFetchTime": "2049",
      "sourceCountValue": "5076",
      "startTime": "1627297279651",
      "processGroupName": "Trading"
    },
    "Destination": {
      "TRADINGDETAILS": {
        "ProcessEndTime": "2021-07-26 16:31:29",
        "completedTime": "1627297289412",
        "processDuration": "10",
        "destCountValue": "5076",
        "tableName": "TRADINGDETAILS"
      },
      "CUSTTRADINGDETAILS": {
        "ProcessEndTime": "2021-07-26 16:31:29",
        "completedTime": "1627297289412",
        "processDuration": "10",
        "destCountValue": "5076",
        "tableName": "CUSTTRADINGDETAILS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use successive **shift** transformations; enumarate the keys of the objects within the first one, and then rename them while nesting each under the related keys such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": "Trading.Source",
      "*": "Trading.Destination.@(0,tableName)"
    }
  }
]
```